# What are the technical differences between truecrypt, bit locker to go and an iron key?

Tags: security, encryption, usb-flash-drive, truecrypt, bitlocker

I am looking to get a new USB drive (my old one took an unauthorized vacation) and am looking into how to secure the data on it.  Ideally I would like a visible, unencrypted space that may or maynot be bootable then an encrypted area for low security files followed by a second encrypted space for the most secure files.

Is there a solution that will handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for bit locker or iron key, but I use TrueCrypt on a USB key as you describe.  Truecrypt allows you to create encrypted volumes in the form of a file.  You can store the encrypted file on your USB key and then use TrueCrypt to mount it at will.  TrueCrypt will even set up a "Traveler Disk" for you that will create an autorun.inf to automatically start TrueCrypt when the USB key is plugged in.  See [this link](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable) for more info.

Just a note, fat32, which is the default fs on most USB keys, has a file size limit of 4GB limit.  I still use fat32 but keep my encrypted partitions below 4GB.  Format with NTFS if you need an encrypted FS over 4GB.

Answer (score 2):

According to wikipedia, the hidden container feature is not available for BitLocker, though you can always create multiple partitions on the USB key, and hide one.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software